# 2 Futures one Stream Flutter

Tags: flutter, dart

I have a problem with Streams. I'm getting null form the stream. My objective is to combine 2 futures so I'm using first future when user has not searched any parameters and other one when user searched because I have 2 endpoints one for searched list and one that has no filters. I'm not really sure if that's standard industry practice for app dev. If its not please tell me so and how should I set up back end

```
Widget Body(BuildContext context, TabController taby) {
  Future<List<littleOffers>> searchdata = null;

  Stream<List<littleOffers>> _dataSwitch() async* {
    if (searchdata == null)
      yield* Stream.fromFuture(fetchOffers());
    else
      yield* Stream.fromFuture(searchdata);
  }

  void resetSearchData() {
    searchdata = null;
  }

  void setSearchData(Future<List<littleOffers>> data) {
    searchdata = data;
  }

  return Column(
    children: <Widget>[
      Search_Sort(context),
      Expanded(
        child: StreamBuilder(
            stream: _dataSwitch(),
            builder: (context, snapshot) {
              if (snapshot.connectionState == ConnectionState.none || !snapshot.hasData) {
                print('project snapshot data is: ${snapshot.data}');
                print('project snapshot state is: ${snapshot.connectionState.toString()}');
                return Container();
              } else {
                return TabBarView(controller: taby, children: [
                  getList(snapshot.data),
                  getList(snapshot.data),
                  getList(snapshot.data),
                  getList(snapshot.data),
                ]);
              }
            }),
      ),
    ],
  );
}
```

Comment: From the backend point of view (provided you are building it too), why would you want to have two endpoints for basically same task? Just send data+params as JSON and process on the backend accordingly - filters on/off or w/e else.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Creating Stream from 2 futures so that one is alway actice and other one is on stand by when switch is needed.

```
Stream<List<littleOffers>> _dataOfferSwitch() async* {
    if (searchOfferData == null)
        yield* Stream.fromFuture(fetchOffers());
    else
        yield* Stream.fromFuture(searchOfferData);}
```

Comment: Please don't post only code as answer, but also provide an explanation what your code does and how it solves the problem of the question. Answers with an explanation are usually more helpful and of better quality, and are more likely to attract upvotes

Answer (score 1):

That could work but I think you missed async and await on setSearchData

```
void setSearchData(Future<List<littleOffers>> newData) {
        setState(()async{
              searchdata = await newData;
          });
      }
```

and to remove data

```
void clearSearchData() {
        setState((){
              searchdata = null;
          });
      }
```

Answer (score 0):

You can define only one `List<littleOffers>` (not future) ;

```dart
Widget Body(BuildContext context, TabController taby) {
      List<littleOffers> searchdata = null;
    
    
      Future<void> setSearchData(Future<List<littleOffers>> newData) async {
        var _data = await newData;
        setState((){
              searchdata = _data;
          });
      }
    
      return Column(
        children: <Widget>[
          Search_Sort(context),
          Expanded(
            child: searchData == null ? Center(child: CircularProcessIndicator()) : yourWidget;
          ),
        ],
      );
    }
```